# Lambda variable shared between translation units

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I have a variable that I share in a header file. It is initialized with a lambda. I wish to call a function from another translation unit, taking this lambda variable as a parameter.

With gcc, I get an error:

> used but never defined [-fpermissive].

Here is a cut down example:

```
// in shared header file
//
const auto make_lambda() { return [](){ }; }
inline const auto lambda = make_lambda();

// in cpp file
//
void func(const decltype(lambda)&);

int main() {
    func(lambda);
}
```

My understanding is that the lambda type should be shared between translation units.

When I alter the lambda variable to the following, the issue goes away:

```
inline const auto lambda = [](){ }; // <-- this does work
```

Comment: `inline` is also missing for `make_lambda`...

Comment: If `make_lambda()` is inlined as shown, then I'm guessing that sharing the header file in multiple translation units will cause each TU to have its own version of `make_lambda()` and thus have separate lambdas with different types, causing the declaration of `func()` in one TU to mismatch with the definition of `func()` in the other TU.  Removing `make_lambda()` solves the problem because then there will only be 1 lambda, not 2 lambdas.

Comment: Yes I need there to be only one lambda shared between TUs and the func declaration to match between TUs so I can call from one to the other.

Comment: Why do you need only one single lambda to be shared between everyone? What is the original and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Why does it need to be a lambda, and not (for example) your own callable object? This is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) at the moment, but if you ask about the original, underlying and actual problem we might be able to help you solve that in a better (and working) way.

Comment: I'm trying to get to the bottom of an issue with a lambda based library, so I've cut the problem down to highlight the issue. I can solve it another way but I would like to try to learn why this isn't possible. To me, the "inline const auto lambda" variable should mean there is one variable available but perhaps decltype(lambda) differs between TUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang provides an excellent diagnostic that explains the problem with `make_lambda` well:

```
<source>:8:6: error: function 'func' is used but not defined in this translation unit,
                     and cannot be defined in any other translation unit because its type
                     does not have linkage
void func(const decltype(lambda)&);
     ^
```

Having "no linkage" means:

> When a name has no linkage, the entity it denotes cannot be referred to by names from other scopes.

- [[basic.link]/2.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#2.4)

The reason why our lambda has no linkage is that the closure type it defines is defined *inside* of `make_lambda`. This results in:

> Names not covered by these rules have no linkage.
> Moreover, except as noted, a name declared at block scope has no linkage.

- [[basic.link]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#7)

The type you're trying to use is `make_lambda::__lambda` essentially, and this cannot be used across different TUs.

#### ODR issues with sharing lambda expressions

```cpp
inline const auto lambda = [](){ };
```

... makes the compiler errors go away, but this makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required. We must respect the one-definition-rule, and we violate the following:

> In each such definition, except within the default arguments and default template arguments of `D`, corresponding lambda-expressions shall have the same closure type (see below).

- [[basic.def.odr]/14.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14.6)

Every TU will have its own unique closure type, but `lambda` must have the same definition everywhere. **This is an ODR violation.**

If you really insisted on doing it, the safe way would be to put it into a class type:

```cpp
struct dummy {
    using lambda_type = [] {};
};
```

`dummy::lambda_type` will have linkage and doesn't violate the ODR.
See also: [[basic.def.odr]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#16)

#### Conclusion

Just don't share lambdas across different TUs. Even if you make it work, the solution isn't pretty. Instead, consider:

- writing a function template that accepts anything callable
- accepting a function pointer
- accepting `std::function`
- creating a regular class, not a lambda, which has an overloaded call operator

All of these options are *much* better than trying to share a lambda expression (outside of functions) across TUs.

Comment: On the lambdas having different closure types -- I thought that there should be one unique closure type for that lambda across all TUs?

Comment: @squashed for `make_lambda` yes, because the closure type is located inside of the function. For `lambda` no, because the lambda expression results in a new closure type being defined somewhere in the TU, so every `lambda` will use a different type. In practice, this could be a problem if a compiler names the closure types `scope::__lambda1`, `scope::__lambda2`, etc. in the order in which they appear in the TU. It's easy to see that you could have `a.cpp` using `__lambda1` in the initializer, and `b.cpp` using `__lambda2`. That's why putting it into a class/function body fixes the problem.